# How to do crossvalidation finetuning of a Transformer model?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, cross-validation

I want to run 10-fold crossvalidation on the finetuning process of a huggingface transformer trainer ([UIE](https://github.com/universal-ie/UIE)). I'm experimenting with the UIE model, which basically works with the basic transformer architecture.

To achieve 10-fold crossvalidation I need to split my dataset into 10 distinct folds, such that the training and evaluation set gets switched around. This image explains it for k=5 ([Source](https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:4600/1*RCAAhv_IFVDK1aLMMsF2uw.png)):
[image: https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:4600/1*RCAAhv_IFVDK1aLMMsF2uw.png]

But the Trainer class wants a `eval_dataset` ([Code](https://github.com/universal-ie/UIE/blob/main/run_uie_finetune.py)).

```
   trainer = ConstraintSeq2SeqTrainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=train_dataset if training_args.do_train else None,
        eval_dataset=eval_dataset if training_args.do_eval else None,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        data_collator=data_collator,
        compute_metrics=compute_metrics if training_args.predict_with_generate else None,
        decoding_type_schema=record_schema,
        decoding_format=data_args.decoding_format,
        source_prefix=prefix,
        task=data_args.task,
    )
```

I know that the validation dataset is not the test set, because in the end of the script the test results are evaluated:

```
if training_args.do_predict:
    logger.info("*** Test ***")

    test_results = trainer.predict(
        test_dataset,
        metric_key_prefix="test",
        max_length=data_args.val_max_target_length,
        num_beams=data_args.num_beams,
    )
    test_metrics = test_results.metrics
    test_metrics["test_loss"] = round(test_metrics["test_loss"], 4)

    output_test_result_file = os.path.join(training_args.output_dir, "test_results_seq2seq.txt")
```

I'm getting errors when I try to pass an empty validation dataset in json or set `eval_dataset` to None. So it appears to me that the Trainer really requires a eval dataset. So I have the following questions:

1. I don't understand why I need a validation set in the first place, I thought that a transformer trains solely on the training set and evaluates the trained model on the test set.
2. If the trainer really requires a validation set, how would I do the the crossvalidaiton?  Most examples show crossvalidation on 2 train_test splits, but not on train_val_test splits.

I implemented and ran it like this and it worked fine, but I think that's missing the point of crossvalidation, since the testset is always the same:
[image: My Crossvalidation implementation]

Comment: That only gets evaluated if you have `do_eval=True` in the `training_args`

Answer (score -1):

you can checkout [Microsoft NNI](https://nni.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hpo/overview.html). It is a framework that helps in tuning of your model and present in a very interactive and intuitive way.

Comment: Sorry, but how does it relate to the question? It sounds like something I already use: Weights and Biases.

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood your question. You can write cross validation as

`n_splits = 10`

`# Initialize cross-validation`

`kf = KFold(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=True, random_state=42)`

`for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):`

    `X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]`

    `y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]`

    `model = YourModelClass()`

    `model.fit(X_train, y_train)` 

    `# Make predictions`

    `# Calculate accuracy score`

Comment: and you can use it with NNI to analyse results in a better way.

Comment: My problem is not the creation of train+test+val sets, but rather how to use them in a hugginface transformer. More specifically, why does a huggingface transformer require a validaiton set. The other question is if my idea of crossvalidation would be right, if transformers are generally trained on train+test+val splits.